# How can I get data from a HTTP post in C# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, http-post, xamarin.forms

I am trying to POST some data using HTTPClient. I have managed to use the following code when simply getting data in JSON format, but it doesn't seem to work for a POST.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public static async Task<SwipeDetails> SaveSwipesToCloud()
{
    //get unuploaded swips
   IEnumerable<SwipeDetails> swipesnotsved =  SwipeRepository.GetUnUploadedSwipes();

    foreach (var item in swipesnotsved)
    {
        //send it to the cloud
        Uri uri = new Uri(URL + "SaveSwipeToServer" + "?locationId=" + item.LocationID + "&userId=" + item.AppUserID + "&ebCounter=" + item.SwipeID + "&dateTimeTicks=" + item.DateTimeTicks + "&swipeDirection=" + item.SwipeDirection + "&serverTime=" + item.IsServerTime );

        HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await myClient.GetAsync(uri);

        //the content needs to update the record in the SwipeDetails table to say that it has been saved.
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the method it's trying to contact. As you can see, the method also returns some data in JSON format so as well as a POST it's also getting some data back which I need to be able to work with:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveSwipeToServer(int locationId, int userId, int ebCounter, long dateTimeTicks, int swipeDirection, int serverTime)
{
    bool result = false;
    string errMsg = String.Empty;
    int livePunchId = 0;
    int backupPunchId = 0;
    IClockPunch punch = null;
    try
    {
        punch = new ClockPunch()
        {
            LocationID = locationId,
            Swiper_UserId = userId,
            UserID = ebCounter,
            ClockInDateTime = DateTimeJavaScript.ConvertJavascriptDateTime(dateTimeTicks),
            ClockedIn = swipeDirection.Equals(1),
        };

        using (IDataAccessLayer dal = DataFactory.GetFactory())
        {
            DataAccessResult dalResult = dal.CreatePunchForNFCAPI(punch, out livePunchId, out backupPunchId);
            if (!dalResult.Result.Equals(Result.Success))
            {
                throw dalResult.Exception;
            }
        }
        result = true;
    }

    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        errMsg = "Something Appeared to go wrong when saving punch information to the horizon database.\r" + ex.Message;
    }
    return Json(new
    {
        result = result,
        punchDetails = punch,
        LivePunchId = livePunchId,
        BackUpPunchId = backupPunchId,
        timeTicks = DateTimeJavaScript.ToJavaScriptMilliseconds(DateTime.UtcNow),
        errorMessage = errMsg
    }
    ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

At the moment the data being stored in 'content' is just an error message.

Comment: If you are passing all of the data via querystring, you can define your action method as a HttpGet operation.  Your request isn't posting any data back.

Comment: Do you have an example? The request is returning Json data at the end.

Comment: if you provide the URI where I can call SaveSwipesToCloud I can give you the sample. I need URI to test the code I write for you

Comment: The simple answer would be to use `PostAsync()` if you want to POST rather than `GetAsync()` which naturally is a GET.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, but he needs to post the data not just call Post and that's what I wanted to test before providing the solution

Comment: @connersz Are you using web api? You might need to send your parameters in the body, not in URI

Comment: @YuriS Do you have an answer for this? I'm afraid I'm fairly new to this so I can't entirely picture the changes required.

Comment: @connersz if you provide the URI where I can call SaveSwipesToCloud I can give you the sample. I need URI to test the code I write for you

Comment: I would also suggest to change your service to public JsonResult SaveSwipeToServer([FromBody]SaveSwipeRequest req){...}

Comment: @YuriS I am unable to change the service. There must be a way to do this in C#. It's working fine in the old javascript version.

Comment: yes, there is, see my answer

Comment: @connersz is this a normal Asp.Net MVC project or Web API project?

Comment: @Nkosi It's a xamarin forms project requesting information from a normal MVC project.

Comment: @connersz are you able to include Web API in the MVC project?

Comment: Then you need to include the name of the controller, possibly the name of your app into URI. There is not enough info to give you definite answer without knowing you URI and controller name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post the parameters in the body of the request.

```
public static async Task<SwipeDetails> SaveSwipesToCloud() {
    //get unuploaded swips
    var swipesnotsved =  SwipeRepository.GetUnUploadedSwipes();

    var client = new HttpClient() {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(URL)
    };
    var requestUri = "SaveSwipeToServer";

    //send it to the cloud
    foreach (var item in swipesnotsved) {

        //create the parameteres
        var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        data["locationId"] = item.LocationID;
        data["userId"] = item.AppUserID;
        data["ebCounter"] = item.SwipeID;
        data["dateTimeTicks"] = item.DateTimeTicks;
        data["swipeDirection"] = item.SwipeDirection;
        data["serverTime"] = item.IsServerTime;

        var body = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, body);

        //the content needs to update the record in the SwipeDetails table to say that it has been saved.
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I tried it but still get the error 500.

Comment: With some tweaks this did the job.

Comment: @connersz, what were the tweaks. Was it to the code presented in the answer? if so let me know so I can update the answer to make it relevant.

Comment: Well the only thing required was that the ints in the parameters needed converting to strings.

Comment: Ok I see. As I didn't know what those property types were in the example I was unaware of that. So I guess there isn't really a need to update the answer then

Comment: Actually the server would not accept them at all, presumably because the Dictionary was set to a type of string. I had to update the web method to accept them all as string before converting them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you host your service, it is not clear from your code. I hosted mine in Web API controller SwipesController in application HttpClientPostWebService. I don't suggest to use JsonResult. For mobile client I would just return the class you need.

You have 2 options:

1. Use get not post.
2. Use post.

Both cases are below

Controller:

```
namespace HttpClientPostWebService.Controllers
{
    public class SwipesController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult SaveSwipeToServer(int locationId, int userId, int ebCounter, long dateTimeTicks, int swipeDirection, int serverTime)
        {
            return Ok(new SwipeResponse
            {
                TestInt = 3,
                TestString = "Testing..."
            });
        }

        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult PostSwipeToServer([FromBody] SwipeRequest req)
        {
            return Ok(new SwipeResponse
            {
                TestInt = 3,
                TestString = "Testing..."
            });
        }

    }

    public class SwipeRequest
    {
        public string TestStringRequest { get; set; }
        public int TestIntRequest { get; set; }
    }

    public class SwipeResponse
    {
        public string TestString { get; set; }
        public int TestInt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
    async private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync(@"http://uri/HttpClientPostWebService/Api/Swipes?locationId=1&userId=2&ebCounter=3&dateTimeTicks=4&swipeDirection=5&serverTime=6");
            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwipeResponse>(content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


        try
        {
            var result1 = await client.PostAsync(@"http://uri/HttpClientPostWebService/Api/Swipes",
                new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SwipeRequest() { TestIntRequest = 5, TestStringRequest = "request" }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            var content1 = await result1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var resp1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwipeResponse>(content1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about the parameters? The problem I'm having at the moment is that the controller is returning the default error page which leads me to think that the parameters are not being passed in correctly.

Comment: @connersz I have asked you few times to provide URI where I can test your service and/or sample project, so I can see your service definitions and test client code

Comment: This site can’t be reached
dev2.core.thinking-software.com’s server DNS address could not be found. I also need to know how you host it. Is it web api, svc, etc?

Comment: I am able to access the page internally and externally. The error message is error 400, bad request. I don't know much about how it's hosted but it's just running on IIS and it's just a method within a controller that's accessed using the link.

Comment: This is my last request for you to provide URI where I can test, after that I give up.

Comment: I have pasted it for you about 4 lines up. It works perfectly, paste it into your web browser. There's nothing more I can do for you. I just need to know how to pass in the parameters.

Comment: And I replied to you that I cannot reach it. You probably going to it from internal network but I cannot reach this site. Parameters are shown in my answer as Get request.